# Uploading aspx file to document library

Tags: file-upload, aspx

I am trying to upload an aspx page to a document library that I use the keep all my pages in.

The immediate thing that sprung to mind was some kind of permissions problem, but this should not be the case since I am the site collection administrator. Just in case this was hiding the issue I gave somebody else the permission "Add and Customize Pages". They got the same error.

The issue happens through the SharePoint UI. With this in mind I wrote a simple stand-alone application in an attempt to upload the file - the important bit of the code follows -

```
SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

string destFileUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
web.Files.Add(destFileUrl, fileStream, true);
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

fileStream.Close();
```

Unfortunately this also encounters the same error. The error message is as follows -

> The URL 'Pages/Credentials.aspx' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is
>   not in the current Web.

"Credentials.aspx" is the file I am trying to upload and "Pages" is the library. I have uploaded non-aspx files to this library with no problem and the same error occurs if I try to upload an aspx file elsewhere.

Please could somebody shine some light on this?

After switching on verbose logging, immediately the error message displayed provided (seemingly) more detail. I have searched around and it seems that people get similar errors doing a variety of different things - but I could not see a pattern or answer to resolve my situation. The following is the new detail -

> 0x81020030owssvr.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000B7EC4) at 0x000007FEE99D7EC4
>   mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BE497) at
>   0x000007FEF414E497 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000E7C3A) at 0x000007FEEB6D7C3A
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001AA1C13) at 0x000007FEEE811C13
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001C4DC06) at 0x000007FEEE9BDC06
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001C4C840) at 0x000007FEEE9BC840 The URL
>   'BistechSystem/Credentials.aspx' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is
>   not in the current Web.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   0x81020030owssvr.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000B7EC4) at 0x000007FEE99D7EC4
>   mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BE497) at
>   0x000007FEF414E497 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved
>   symbol, module offset=00000000000E7C3A) at 0x000007FEEB6D7C3A
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001AA1C13) at 0x000007FEEE811C13
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001C4DC06) at 0x000007FEEE9BDC06
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module
>   offset=0000000001C4C840) at 0x000007FEEE9BC840 The URL
>   'BistechSystem/Credentials.aspx' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is
>   not in the current Web.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic error so you need to know what is causing SharePoint to throw that error.

Could you please try enabling SharePoint verbose logging?

To do this go to

> Central Administration

then

> Monitoring

then

> Configure Diagnostic logging.

Now you need to try and upload the aspx file again to the document library again using SharePoint user interface.

You now need to analyse the logs using correlating ID,

Now you should be able to see the error in full detail :).

Post back the error if you cant fix or know where to look else after that you need to perform an IISreset

this is an easy way to log 
http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

or

Create Loging like eventViewer
http://jbaurle.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/how-to-implement-a-custom-sharepoint-2010-logging-service-for-uls-and-windows-event-log/

to configure the logging:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx#section2

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my post with the additional information. It would be great if you can have a look.

Comment: iv neva had this prob n cant help you that much but from what i can see is that it cant find the location for some reason and i suspect it might have to do with SQL its maybe referencing to a folder that doesnt exist or its a missmatch between SQL and doc library. Have a look at this and see if you can follow the steps its somthing similar to your issue:

Comment: http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/the-url-msrs100ds1essrsds-is-invalid-it-may-refer-to-a-nonexistent-file-folder-refer-to-18639.shtml and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/sharepoint2010setup/thread/ed1bc2e0-0969-4ff0-adc8-cd5ca022f9af

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
string destFileUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
```

Try using

```
string destFileUrl = list.RootFolder + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
```